# Linux command line utility to resolve host names using /etc/hosts first

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, hostname

There are several command line utilities to resolve host names (`host`, `dig`, `nslookup`), however they all use nameservers exclusively, while applications in general look in `/etc/hosts` first (using gethostbyname I believe).

Is there a command line utility to resolve host names that behaves like a usual application, thus looking in `/etc/hosts` first and only then asking a nameserver?

(I am aware that it would probably be like 3 lines of c, but I need it inside of a somewhat portable shell script.)

Comment: Could you please explain your situation a little more? Does `awk '/hostname/ { print $1 }' /etc/hosts` help?

Comment: @quanta Actually the current solution is grep/sed magic on /etc/hosts. I wanted to make that more general with a fallback.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

This is easily achieved with `getent`:

```
getent hosts 127.0.0.1
```

`getent` will do lookups for any type of data configured in `nsswitch.conf`.

Comment: This is the tool I use in my Alpine docker containers that have no other mechanism like `dig` or `nslookup`.

Comment: For those interested to read more on `getent`'s intention: https://www.computerworld.com/article/2812084/getting-an-entry-with-getent.html

Answer (score 33):

One tool that would work is [`getent`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/getent).  So you could use `getent hosts www.google.com`, or `getent hosts localhost`.  It will retrieve entries from the databases as specified in your Name Service Switch configuration [`/etc/nsswitch.conf`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/nsswitch.conf).

For more modern implementations use `getent ahosts www.google.com` which will get multiple results.

Comment: Yes, but that would not fall back on DNS.

Comment: No, it resolves it in nsswitch.conf order.

Comment: @slowpoison, Take a look at your nsswitch config.  My system has `files dns` for hosts, which means /etc/hosts is consulted and then the DNS resolver.  Your config may be different.

Comment: @cjc, it does. I don't think I tried it correctly.

Comment: @Zoredache, I'm quite impressed with `getent`. Thanks for the intro to this command.

Comment: It's a helpful tool, but why use it to do a lookup in the /etc/hosts file which has been deprecated since about 2 decades, give or take? Thank goodness tools such as ping ignore the hosts file. There are other ways to accomplish these things, such as adding your own custom zone files to your nameserver.

Answer (score 12):

Use `getent ahosts`, for instance:

```
$ getent ahosts www.google.com | sed -n 's/ *STREAM.*//p'
216.58.210.196
2a00:1450:4006:803::2004
```

You'll get all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, via the glibc resolver (thus using `/etc/hosts` first, as usually configured in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`).

Do not use `getent hosts`, as it will give you either IPv6 or IPv4 addresses (not both), and the chosen protocol may not be one that does not work. Indeed, IPv6 addresses are generally preferred, but at some places, IPv6 data are filtered (not supported) by the routers.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: This indeed is the correct answer for me because `You'll get all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses`.

Answer (score 10):

You can use a gethostbyname() (deprecated) wrapper like:

```
python -c 'import socket;print socket.gethostbyname("www.google.com")'
```

Or a getaddrinfo() wrapper like:

```
python -c 'import socket;print socket.getaddrinfo("www.google.com","http")[0][4][0]'
```

For python3:

```
python -c 'import socket;print(socket.getaddrinfo("www.google.com","http")[0][4][0])'
```

Note that getaddrinfo will return all instances as a list. The last part of the command selects only the first tuple. This can also return IPv6 addresses.

Comment: This will work, but it's been obsolete for a while.  See http://linux.die.net/man/3/gethostbyname.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about it. ;)

Comment: Have an upvote.  No other semi-portable one-liner has been proposed.

Comment: In case this is of value to anyone else, I made a Python 3 version with a few command-line options: https://github.com/acdha/unix_tools/blob/master/bin/getaddrinfo

Answer (score 7):

`resolveip` will do this.

Oddly, it's part of the mysql-server packages on RHEL and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 7):

You could use [your favorite language here] to write a script that calls [getnameinfo](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getnameinfo).  That is how binaries (like ping) should be doing it, so you're ensured you get the same treatment.

Answer (score 6):

You could be really hacky and use `arp`:

```
arp -n somehostname | tr -d '()' | awk '{print $2}'
```

but that would be really ugly so you shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 4):

"gethostbyname" [command line version](http://www.documentroot.com/2012/02/gethostbyname-command-line.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Socket;

$host = shift @ARGV;
die("usage: gethostbyname hostname\n") unless(defined($host));

$packed_ip = gethostbyname($host);

if (defined $packed_ip) {
    $ip_address = inet_ntoa($packed_ip);
    print "$ip_address\n";
    exit 0
} else {
    warn "$host not found\n";
    exit 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if [ `grep -c "hostname" /etc/hosts` -ge 1 ]; then
    ip=`awk '/hostname/ { print $1 }' /etc/hosts`
else
    ip=`host hostname | awk '/hostname has address/ { print $4 }'`
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

`getent hosts` is broken. It prefers IPv6 addresses, `gai.conf` should be configured to prefer ipv4 but....

The Perl `gethostbyname` uses the precedence in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`

```
hosts: files dns
```

So this works like `getent hosts` should work for me.

Also:

```
perl -e 'use Socket; print inet_ntoa(inet_aton("www.google.com")) . "\n";'
```

should work.

Comment: It's not broken, it just doesn't use getaddrinfo (which reads /etc/gai.conf). To use getaddrinfo, run `getent ahosts`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Debian-based distro:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libsocket-getaddrinfo-perl
socket_getaddrinfo one.one.one.one

# Resolved host 'one.one.one.one', service '0'
# 
# socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) + '1.1.1.1:0'
# socket(AF_INET , SOCK_DGRAM , IPPROTO_UDP) + '1.1.1.1:0'
# socket(AF_INET , SOCK_RAW   , IPPROTO_IP ) + '1.1.1.1:0'
# socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) + '1.0.0.1:0'
# socket(AF_INET , SOCK_DGRAM , IPPROTO_UDP) + '1.0.0.1:0'
# socket(AF_INET , SOCK_RAW   , IPPROTO_IP ) + '1.0.0.1:0'
# socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) + '[2606:4700:4700::1111]:0'
# socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM , IPPROTO_UDP) + '[2606:4700:4700::1111]:0'
# socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_RAW   , IPPROTO_IP ) + '[2606:4700:4700::1111]:0'
# socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) + '[2606:4700:4700::1001]:0'
# socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM , IPPROTO_UDP) + '[2606:4700:4700::1001]:0'
# socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_RAW   , IPPROTO_IP ) + '[2606:4700:4700::1001]:0'

socket_getaddrinfo localhost

# Resolved host 'localhost', service '0'
# 
# socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) + '[::1]:0'
# socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM , IPPROTO_UDP) + '[::1]:0'
# socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_RAW   , IPPROTO_IP ) + '[::1]:0'
# socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) + '127.0.0.1:0'
# socket(AF_INET , SOCK_DGRAM , IPPROTO_UDP) + '127.0.0.1:0'
# socket(AF_INET , SOCK_RAW   , IPPROTO_IP ) + '127.0.0.1:0'
```

Answer (score -1):

The following command will perform lookup via DNS /etc/hosts over direct DNS server lookup.

```
ping -W2 -c1 google.com | grep PING | sed -r "s/^[^\(]*\(([\.0-9]*)\).*/\1/"
```

This command  will attempt to ping a domain (in this case, google.com) once with a wait timeout of 2 seconds, get the first line of the PING command which will state "PING google.com (216.58.199.36) 56(84) bytes of data", then use Stream Editor (sed) to detect the first set of brackets and extract the data within it which is the IP address we are looking for.

NOTE: the regex expression will not work if there are parenthesis (aka circular brackets) in the URL, but this would be a rare case.