# What's the cleanest way to do a hostname lookup on a Linux system, that checks /etc/hosts first?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linux command line utility to resolve host names wrt. /etc/hosts](https://serverfault.com/questions/303716/linux-command-line-utility-to-resolve-host-names-wrt-etc-hosts)

Let's say I have an entry in my /etc/hosts

```
1.2.3.4 example.com
```

To look up example.com, I can use the commands like *host*, *nslookup* and *dig*, but they only do a DNS lookup (while ignoring /etc/hosts). I want a clean and easy way to run

```
mylookupcmd example.com
```

that first checks /etc/hosts and if that fails, does a DNS lookup.

I can do

```
ping example.com | my-scraper-that-outputs-ip-address
```

and get the IP address, but that's not a "clean" solution.