# intranet dns lookup fetching incorrect ip

Tags: centos7, internal-dns

We have a host entry on our server in `/etc/hosts` file. So there is an entry as follows:

```
10.74.74.76 foo
```

But on the same machine, via SSH I do the following:

```
$ host -t a foo
foo.internal.domain.com has address 10.43.55.23
```

Why is this not referencing the ip in `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linux command line utility to resolve host names using /etc/hosts first](https://serverfault.com/questions/303716/linux-command-line-utility-to-resolve-host-names-using-etc-hosts-first)

Answer (score 0):

[`host`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/host) is a (simple) ***DNS lookup*** utility.

Any data in your `/etc/hosts` file is NOT DNS.

That means that the `host` command will always query the DNS servers you have configured and it does not honor the typical precedence your system resolver uses  in first querying the local hosts database before attempting to resolve the host/FQDN.

Answer (score 0):

The `host` command is a DNS lookup utility that always uses DNS as a resolver; never `/etc/hosts` file.

From host(1) man page:

> `host` is a simple utility for performing DNS lookups.
>
> `server` is an optional argument which is either the name or IP address of the name server that host should query instead of the server or servers listed in `/etc/resolv.conf`.